# Configuring TFS to show diff for the office files

Tags: tfs, diff

How can i configure TFS (maybe there is a setting or extension) to show diff between office openxml files (like .xlsx or docx). Now the TFS (online) just shows yellow banner like one below. I want to have side-by-side diff.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If such an extension exists, you will find it on the [VSTS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts), but unfortunately none produced a smart binary file differ like WinMerge or Beyond Compare.

The OpenXML format is a Zip containing many XML files, a text compare is useless. Your options are:

- download the two versions and use Office (yes it has built-in diff for docs) or a tool like Beyond Compare (it may requires some plugin)
- move to text based formats like CSV or Markdown

Comment: The diff does not need to be fancy. Just a plain text diff will suffice. Any ideas for a non-smart plain diff?

Comment: Added to the answer

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm after.. I just want that yellow thing to show plain text diff instead. I.e. I don't expect it to show formatting or anything fancy like that. Just plain text. BUT in the browser :)

Comment: Write the extension yourself.

Comment: Is it possible  to write a diff extension?

Comment: Yes, but take this off-line: send me an email